# Accessing Multidimensional Object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Ok. After about an hour of trying to think of different ways to do this, my noobness is prevailing (and this question will prove it).

I have a JSON object that looks like so:

```
{
    newEvent: {
        Event: {
            name: "Something",
            timestamp: {
                month: "07",
                day: "27",
                year: "2013",
                hour: "07",
                min: "42",
                meridian: "pm"
            },
            duration: "2",
            durationMeasure: "min"
        }
    },
    msg: "Event Added"
}
```

It gets returned in a jquery ajax complete callback function thingy, so its sitting inside a param called `data`.
Using Chrome, I can `console.log()` `data`,`data.newEvent`,`data.msg`,`data['newEvent']`,and `data['msg']`. The only one that returns anything other than undefined, is `data` (which prints what's above)

My question: How in the WORLD do I get to anything in `data`?! Any insight for a JavaScript noob would be greatly appreciated! =)

EDIT:
A code snippet:

```
function eventAdditionalFinish(data,textStatus) {
    console.log("data: ",data,"\n");
    console.log("data['newEvent']: ",data['newEvent'],"\n");
    console.log("data['msg']: ",data['msg'],"\n");

    console.log("data.newEvent: ",data.newEvent,"\n");
    console.log("data.msg: ",data.msg,"\n");
}
```

Output from Chrome's console:

```
data:  {"newEvent":{"Event":{"name":"Something","timestamp":{"month":"07","day":"27","year":"2013","hour":"07","min":"42","meridian":"pm"},"duration":"2","durationMeasure":"min"}},"msg":"Event Added"}
data['newEvent']:  undefined 
data['msg']:  undefined 
data.newEvent:  undefined 
data.msg:  undefined
```

Comment: works fine when referenced by name thusly: http://jsfiddle.net/uCPFP/... what's the rest of your code look like? (tested in Firefox and Chromium, at least)

Comment: That's no JSON, it's just a JS object, but your code should work...

Comment: @mohkhan actually thats a C&P fail. There were a few things after durationMeasure I excluded from this object. Thanks though. =)

Comment: @PeteScott I added the actual function.

Comment: How are you parsing the returned data? jQuery's intellisense, or are you declaring `dataType:json`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Sorry, I dont have a CLUE what you just asked. Ha =/

Comment: Oberst, I updated the jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/uCPFP/1/) and it's still functioning when passed an actual object... updated again: http://jsfiddle.net/uCPFP/2/

Comment: @PeteScott Wow... It IS still working. O_o Crazy! Ok. Perhaps I missed something then. Thanks for that Pete!

Comment: @PeteScott Its being made by a PHP `json_encode` from data that gets passed to it from a form.

Comment: Can you post the bit that passes it to your eventAdditionalFinish() function?

Comment: Thanks for the help @PeteScott ! I got it going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

if you use jQuery's `json()` function in place of `ajax()`, it will parse the response into a json object.

If, however, you're using the stock functions and getting the result as a string called `data` then you need something like this to convert it into an object...

```
response = JSON.parse(data);
```

you can then do...

```
response.newEvent.blah;
```

as you'd expect.

Note that your example isn't actually valid json. Property names should be quoted...

```
{
    "newEvent": {
        "Event": {
            "name": "Something",
            "timestamp": {
                "month": "07",
                ...
```

As someone else has pointed out, you could also tell `ajax()` to convert the result to an object for you (exactly as if you'd called `json()`) by specifying the data type...

```
$.ajax({
     ...
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data) {
         alert(data.newEvent.Event.name);   
     }
});
```

Comment: My pleasure. Do check out http://json.org/ for the definitive json syntax. Javascript (and many other languages) often support a more lax interpretation of the standard but you might run into problems when you use a new library/language and realise it doesn't support the syntax you're using

Comment: I will definitely read that a little bit later! No idea that site existed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because you receive a string back from the server. So two options:

- Specify `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax parameters.
- Or use `JSON.parse(data)` before trying to access the elements

Comment: Sorry. `JSON.parse(data)` is what I needed. But Basic beat you to the answer by 35 secs. =P Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

The following notation should work, just tested it with a similar example

```
$.ajax({
         url:    'yoururl',
         success: function(data) {
             alert(data.newEvent.Event.name);   
         },
         async:   false
    });
```

What you will get as the data variable in this case is an object with attributes. To access the attributes write: ObjectsName.attributeName

if there are attributes that are also objects containing attributes, those ones can be accessed like: ObjectsName.attributeName1.attrubteName2    (where attribute1 is also an object containing attributes)

Please correct me if im wrong here, im also new to javascript/jquery-ajax but i had the same problem yesterday:)